# ggplot2: create a plot using selected facets with part data

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet, facet-wrap, facet-grid

I would like to create a plot with

1. Using part of the data to create a base plot with `facet_grid` of two columns.
2. Use remaining part of the data and plot on top of the existing facets but using only a single column.

The sample code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

df2 <- data.frame(Class=rep(c('A','B','C'),each=20), 
                 Type=rep(rep(c('T1','T2'),each=10), 3),
                 X=rep(rep(1:10,each=2), 3),
                 Y=c(rep(seq(3,-3, length.out = 10),2), 
                    rep(seq(1,-4, length.out = 10),2), 
                    rep(seq(-2,-8, length.out = 10),2)))

g2 <- ggplot() + geom_line(data = df2 %>% filter(Class %in% c('B','C')),
                           aes(X,Y,color=Class, linetype=Type)) + 
  facet_grid(Type~Class)

g3 <- ggplot() + geom_line(data = df2 %>% filter(Class == 'A'), 
                           aes(X,Y,color=Class, linetype=Type)) + 
  facet_wrap(~Type)

grid.arrange(g2, g3)
```

The output plots:

[image]

How to include `g3` plot on `g2` plot? The resulting plot should include the `g3` two lines twice on two facets.

Comment: Duplicate your data: filter out the `A` class, copy it, set class to `B` in one copy and `C` in the other, recombine. Then add the layer to `g2` with the recombined data.

Comment: I guess you are trying to work on my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48464000/ggplot2-facetting-plot-with-the-same-reference-plot-in-all-panels. ---- Thanks for your effort.

Comment: @ Gregor, this makes sense for data frames with only very few levels. My question (to which @Prradeps questions refers) contains a very simplified example df. The real df will contain n levels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the plot below is what you were looking for.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
df_1 <- filter(df2, Class %in% c('B','C')) %>% 
 dplyr::rename(Class_1 = Class)
df_2 <- filter(df2, Class == 'A') 

g2 <- ggplot() + 
 geom_line(data = df_1,
           aes(X, Y, color = Class_1, linetype = Type)) +
 geom_line(data = df_2,
           aes(X, Y, color = Class, linetype = Type)) +
 facet_grid(Type ~ Class_1)
g2
```

[image]

**explaination**

For tasks like this I found it better to work with two datasets. Since the variable `df2$class` has three unique values: `A`, `B` and `C`, faceting `Class~Type` does not give you desired plot, since you want the data for `df2$Class == "A"` to be displayed in the respective facets.

That's why I renamed variable `Class` in `df_1` to `Class_1` because this variable only contains two unique values: `B` and `C`. 
Faceting `Class_1 ~ Type` allows you to plot the data for `df2$Class == "A"` on top without being faceted by `Class`.

**edit**

Based on the comment below here is a solution using only one dataset

```
g2 + geom_line(data = filter(df2, Class == 'A')[, -1], 
               aes(X, Y, linetype = Type, col = "A"))
```

---

Similar / same question: [ggplot2:: Facetting plot with the same reference plot in all panels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48464000/ggplot2-facetting-plot-with-the-same-reference-plot-in-all-panels/48467689#48467689)